# Como configurar o Laravel 4 para detectar automaticamente em qual ambiente eu estou (produção e desenvolvimento)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

No `Laravel 4`, temos um arquivo de configuração em `app/config/database.php`. E na pasta `app/config/local/database.php` você tem outro arquivo.

O `Laravel 4` possui um mecanismo para poder detectar em qual ambiente estamos (parece-me que é através do nome do computador da pessoa), e assim, podemos determinar se ela vai usar o `database.php` em produção e o `local/database.php` durante o desenvolvimento.

Com configurar o `Laravel 4` para detectar o ambiente de acordo com o `host` que eu estou usando?

Tenho  um virtual host chamado `laravel` na minha máquina e gostaria que, quando eu estiver usando o `Laravel` nesse host, automaticamente seja determinado como ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Existe uma maneira de fazer isso no `Laravel 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve usar o método `Illuminate\Foundation\Application::detectEnviroment()`. É aquela objeto que está armazenado na variável global `$app`. Você deve passar como argumento desse método um `array` ou um `função anônima`. No caso da função `anônima`, deverá fazer uma condição que retorna uma string contendo a palavra `local` para ambientes de desenvolvimento, `test` para ambientes de `test` e `production` para o de produção.

Nesse caso, para usarmos a configuração presente em `config/local/database.php`, vamos verificar o host e então retornar `local` caso o mesmo seja `laravel` ou `localhost`.

Isso é possível no laravel 4 através de um arquivo chamado `bootstrap/start.php`, onde pode ser feita essa configuração incluindo o seguinte código:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() use($app) {

    $host = $app['request']->server('HTTP_HOST');

    if (in_array($host, ['localhost', 'laravel'])) {

        return 'local';

    } 

    return 'production';

});
```