# Como faço para executar o Artisan num ambiente específico?

Tags: laravel, artisan

Como posso fazer para executar o `Artisan` como um ambiente específico?

Pois quando eu rodo

```
 php artisan tinker
```

É gerando um erro por ele estar reconhecendo a configuração do banco de dados de produção. Mas preciso rodá-lo no ambiente `"local"`, pois tenho configurações de banco diferente nesse ambiente.

Não quero ter que alterar o meu arquivo `bootstrap/start.php` e verificar se está rodando pelo console através de `$app->runningInConsole()`, pois, quando eu fizer a atualização dos meus dados no servidor, quero que o `artisan` rode em ambiente de produção.

Alguém sabe definir o ambiente em que o `Artisan` em tempo de execução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode ser resolvido de maneira bem simples. Basta você utilizar a opção `--env=nome_do_ambiente` para fazer com que o `artisan` reconheça outro ambiente.

Exemplo:

```
  php artisan tinker --env=local
```

Isso faz com que o `artisan` capture todas as configurações que você definiu na pasta `config/local`.

Para testar, você pode usar o seguinte exemplo:

```
#app/config/app.php

 'debug' => false


#app/config/local/app.php

'debug' => true
```

Para testarmos as configurações do ambiente `local`, você pode fazer isso:

```
php artisan tinker --env=local

> Config::get('app.debug');
true
```

Para testar o ambiente de produção, basta utilizar a opção `production`, ou não passar nenhum argumento opcional (salvo se você não tiver configurado o arquivo `bootstrap/start.php` - [Leia sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113701/como-configurar-o-laravel-4-para-detectar-automaticamente-em-qual-ambiente-eu-es)).

```
php artisan tinker 

> Config::get('app.debug');
false
```